# Why is it that I can't use DriveApp methods when I link my GAS to a standard GCP?

Tags: google-apps-script, logging, web-applications

I have linked my GAS to a standard GCP so that I can view the logs when I run my external web app, there was no problem initially when I was using the default GCP for my GAS and I could use DriveApp to save some file in google drive and get its link to save in a spread sheet, but after switching to a standard GCP, I can no longer access DriveApp methods as shown in the image below.

Is there some kind of configuration I should make for my standard GCP?

[image]

Comment: Re authorize your script.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: just run any function in the editor. If that doesn't trigger authorization, remove your app from your Google account first.

Comment: hey there! did the solution provided above resolve your issue? @Mireodon